# Automated testing the swipe feature in Node.js application

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I have Node.js application and testing it via Chromedriver and Mocha, the tests are written in javascript. Recently there is a new feature that contains the swipe feature on mobile devices. Is it possible to test it somehow in automated way on the Chrome browser?

Comment: Does the swiping action happen in the front end?

Comment: Yes, by users. They are scrolling the list.

Comment: I think you have to write your own screen function, cuz Mocha is for back end Node, not for the front end JS